# Does (embedded) SWF notify the user if they need to upgrade Flash?

Tags: flash, embedded-flashplayer

if the swf is for flash player **9** but the user only has player **8** installed, will the user get an option to upgrade his player automatically?

Comment: How about you try it and tell us what you find out? Can I call you user552questions49%accept_more_down_votes_than_up_and_precious_few_of them?

Comment: @msw , I have installed newest flash player,so can't test

Comment: I believe that if your object tag has the correct ID and path to the appropriate version of Flash then it will be loaded if not present.

Comment: Can someone edit the title on this question?  Should be something like "Does (embedded) SWF notify the user if they need to upgrade Flash?"

Comment: @user522questions: too bad it is impossible to uninstall software and install old versions

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes!

I think since Flash Player 7 Macromedia added Express Install and the Flash Player Detection Kit. You can read more about that in this [old article http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/express_install.html](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/express_install.html).

Easiest way these days is using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). There are even code generator in plain [html](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_generator_1_2_html.zip) or [air](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_generator_1_2_air.zip).

The idea is, you have an expressInstall.swf which handles the install and a bit of javascript that does the detection and all that. SWFObject already has that built-in, just check the Express Install option in the generator.

HTH

Comment: So there's no such feature out of box?

Comment: @user198729 If you're using Flash CS5, in Publish Settings, under the HTML tab, tick 'Detect Flash Version' - this way the html will be publish using swfobject. You will need to add expressInstall.swf(it also comes swfobject). There is a variable(xiSwfUrlStr) setup in the published html code.

If you don't use Flash CS5 this post(http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=348484) might help for 'out of the box' tips.

Comment: @user198729 This is confusing. I didn't know what you meant by using the 'embedded-flashplayer' tag. I thought there were the Flash Lite player versions and recently Flash Player 10.1 for mobile devices. Flash Player 8 and 9 in your question are misleading. There is no Flash Player 8 for mobile, but I guess Flash Lite 2.1 would be somewhat of an equivalent. Can you explain which platfom and which actual version are you planning to use ? I don't know if there is an express install for mobile phones. I thought there's just the  pre-installed version.